# What command can I use to change the output location of MPlayer?

Tags: command-line, webcam, screenshot, mplayer

I'm using `mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://` to make MPlayer take a single shot from my webcam.

Currently, it saves it to the desktop. What command can I use to make it save the file to `/var/www/html` instead?

I know that it uses your working directory by default. So you can do

```
cd /var/www/html
mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://
```

That will save the photo to the right folder, but it's not a clean solution.

Is there an argument to change the save location without using `cd` though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way:

```
mplayer -vo png:outdir=/var/www/html -frames 1 tv://
```

but it does not work for me. I do not know why.

But this works:

```
mplayer -vo jpeg:outdir=/var/www/html -frames 1 tv://
```

Comment: `sudo mplayer -vo png:outdir=/var/www/html -frames 1 tv://` works for me. Were you getting a permission error? Try it with sudo

Comment: I use another directory that does not require `sudo`. It is good that it works for you. I get a `could not parse output=...` error. it depends on a package version.